Credential form positioned too low
I have a screen where the user has to put some credentials and either choose to sign up or to login. I added alignment top center(under return Container in the beginning) but still doesn't help.
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Logo()),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

Sign up button problem
class SignUpButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Nume si Prenume',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Antra',
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black)),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Antra',
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black)),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 62,
            width: 350,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                  )),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])
        ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Here it's a picture of what outcome i get
This is the new outcome I get
Added alignment , trying scaffold with scroll view , still nothing works.

Can you include an image what are you trying to archive

please add parent widget code that call the LoginButton widget, because when I run the code with placing it on the scaffold (Scaffold > LoginButton) in my local the position of the username, email & button is already on the top
screenshot: https://ibb.co.com/4mP02bz

Hey , I modified the code a bit , any idea?

Just wrap you widgets inside a column instead of a container like this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stack_overflow_questions/stopwatch/stop_watch.dart';

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Nume si Prenume',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Antra',
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Email',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Antra',
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 62,
                    width: 300,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                          )),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 62,
                    width: 300,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        '        I already have account',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const StopWatch()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

this will look much cleaner; And also, if you want to have them at the center of your screen, just add MainAxisAlignment.center to your column like this:
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  ...

edit:
try to remove Expanded from your code. Here is the modified version:
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Logo(),
                SignUpButton(),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const LoginButton(),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}


Hey I modified the code a bit , still doesn't work what you send me to modify , it appears nothing on screen if I do this

@Lili There are clearly some flaws in your code in terms of UI. you have put your Logo() inside the Expanded widget which makes it to take the whole available space of your column. I will edit my answer so you can modify your code again

You're most welcome @Lili , anytime.
